# Laravel get input when name field is unkown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a dynamic form which loops through an input field and pulls in a dynamic name for each input. How can I use `$request->input('')` on an unknown name tag. I also want to validate these fields but not my name field, so I need to tell the differance between the looped field & the input.

Example fieldset -

```
<form id="" method="post" action="{{ route('orderStore') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }} 

   <input id="name" type="text" name="full-name" />

    @forelse($options as $option)
    <select class="ticket-qty" name="{{ $option->id }}">
        <option value="0">0 Option</option>
        <option value="1">1 Option</option>
        <option value="2">2 Option</option>
        <option value="3">3 Option</option>
        <option value="4">4 Option</option>
        <option value="5">5 Option</option>
    </select>
    @empty
        <p>Sorry, no inputs fields</p>
    @endforelse
</form>
```

I understand you can use, `$request->all();` but I have no way to tell if the name is an option or any other input field.

Comment: Use array input field what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use one hidden array input to pass ids and separate selectors to select options like this.

```
<form id="" method="post" action="{{ route('orderStore') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }} 

<input id="name" type="text" name="full-name" />

@forelse($options as $option)
    <input name="option_id[]" value="{{ $option->id }}" hidden>
    <select class="ticket-qty" name="option_selected[]">
        <option value="0">0 Option</option>
        <option value="1">1 Option</option>
        <option value="2">2 Option</option>
        <option value="3">3 Option</option>
        <option value="4">4 Option</option>
        <option value="5">5 Option</option>
    </select>
    @empty
        <p>Sorry, no inputs fields</p>
    @endforelse
</form>
```

Now, at the backend you can access these values like,

```
@foreach($request->option_id as $key=>$value){
    // here $value is option id 
    // $request->option_selected[$key] is the selected option of the above id
}
```

I hope you will understand.

Comment: I'm a little confused & was unable to get your solution to work. Is this a better route than prepending the name field with a value e.g. ```name="option-{{ $ticket->id }}```

Comment: @SamXronn Similar way but quiet easier as well nothing to do extra on backend to retrieve id from the name attribute :D

Comment: @SamXronn As I think you need id value to do some operation in backend, so if you pass that with separate input field then you can use simple foreach to get desired data.

Comment: I understand you're method now thank you for your help

Comment: @SamXronn I feel happy it helped you :D